# Upgrade old project to capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

We are working right now with Ruby, Cucumber and Selenium to perform our integration tests.

Right now we want to improve the quality of our tests and therefore we want to use Capybara.

Now since all our methods need to be rewritten for that, we thought maybe someone has already done that and wrote a wrapper for the selenium webdriver, where Capybara does the job.

For example:

The wrapper should replace the following:

```
driver.navigate_to "/home"
```

to something like

```
visit "/home"
```

The point is, we don´t want to rewrite all our code, since the functionality out of my view is quite of the same and it should not be that difficult to write a wrapper for driver, which does this automatically. Means: the navigate_to method just calls a visit method, and I am happy.

Do I have to write this on my own, or was this already done?

Thanks alot!

Comment: I don't think that that exists, you should rewrite your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no existing wrapper for that.

You seem to be missing the fact that Capybara is itself a wrapper around selenium-webdriver, so you are asking for a selenium compatible wrapper around a wrapper around selenium.  This coupled with the fact that if all you do is emulate your existing selenium commands with Capybara commands you won't be gaining anything from Capybara, so it's pointless.  It sounds like your team would be better off leaving the existing tests as they are, writing all new tests using Capybara, and as existing tests need change/maintenance rewriting them to use Capybara with it's built-in waiting/retrying and friendlier API.

Comment: I already understood that, but it doesn´t change my Problem that I have a lot of old tests which I do not want to rewrite. That is, what i already wrote, exactly the problem. Navigate_to and visit do the same thing, just that visit is better.

Comment: @MJohnyJ `visit` is no better than `navigate` in fact when Capybara is used with Selenium it just boils down to  `def visit(path)
    browser.navigate.to(path)
  end`   As I stated in my answer, don't rewrite the current tests until they need to be changed, and just start writing new tests using Capybara.

Comment: The thing is, that they have to be changed. Many tests fail randomly. To fight this behaviour, in the past we added delays and many wait untils. 
These slow down the tests and still the test fail at random. We hope to fix this with Capybara but since we are talking about 2000 lines of code, another fix must be found

Comment: @MJohnyJ Then you're not going to just be able to write a wrapper for current selenium code and expect Capybara to magically fix your tests.  You will need to rewrite the flaky tests anyway, so leave your stable tests as they are and rewrite the flaky ones to correctly use Capybara.  There is no silver bullet for your issues.

Comment: I see what you mean. I already started working on each test. Thanks for your advice!